# Looping through column data and applying different numerical values inbetween strings VBA

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a function that loops through column values and applies numbers 1,2,3...n in between cells with strings. for example:

data:

```
hefew
1
3
2
6
bkifew
3
4
2
1
3
```

I want the function to change the values to:

```
hefew
  1
  1
  1
  1
bkifew
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
```

There could be multiple strings, so the end value could end up being 15 or so.

I have started a basic function but I am not familiar enough with VBA to work the logic. I program in Python and would normally do stuff like this in that language. However, I'm forced to keep this within excel.

current working:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    cellcount = CountA("A1:A1000")

    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cell In rng
        a = cell.Value
        If IsNumeric(a) = True Then
            cell.Value = 1
        Else
            cell.Value = 0
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I don't think this is possible with a for loop. Is there some sort of search and replace function that I could use?

Comment: First concept you need to look into is `lastrow`, to determine to where your code needs to run. Then you need to loop `from 1 to lastrow` replacing numbers with a counter value, which you increment by one if the cell value you encounter is not a number. Be carefull with the representation of number, look out for differences between integers and other sort of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assuming the numbers are not the result of formulae.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, n As Long

For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
    n = n + 1
    r.Value = n
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it the `.Areas` part that keeps the segmentation between strings in place?

Comment: Yes, this worked! I will look into the documentation to understand SpecialCells. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Luuklag - yes, there are quite a few SC options.

Comment: Note to self, use SC more often ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a function instead of sub which is little bit messy but it works. Tested at my pc

```
Public Function Test(checkrange As Range, checkcell As Range)

Dim cll As Range
Dim arr() As Variant

ReDim Preserve arr(1 To checkrange.Cells.Count)

If IsNumeric(checkcell.Value) = False Then
    Test = checkcell.Value
    Exit Function
End If

y = 1
For Each cll In checkrange
    If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
        arr(y) = 1
    Else
        arr(y) = 0
    End If
    y = y + 1
Next cll

m = 1
For Each cll In checkrange
    If cll.Address = checkcell.Address Then
        rownumber = m
        Exit For
    End If
    m = m + 1
Next cll

m = 0
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i) = 0 Then
        m = m + 1
    End If
    If i = rownumber Then Exit For
Next i

Test = m

End Function
```